# Highlighting duplicates based on the column name with different color

Tags: vba, excel

Could you please suggest me how to highlight the duplicates in the column at one single click. I am in need to write the code in VB Script and will run using a macro in the Excel Spreadsheet. I dont want to give the data validation to a column or conditional formatting to highlight the duplcates.

I need to highlight the column based on its coulmn name (In one single column, I need to highlight duplicates with different color for different value).

For eg. I have 20+ coulmns in my sheet. I need to highlight duplicates for Employee ID, Register number, Role,... among the 20 columns. For your information, These columns name will always not be in a fixed order..

So asking to highlight based a Value.. (Row 1 is fixed and there comes the topic name always )..

Please help me on this!

Thanks in advance..

Below is my code.. This is working fine but however it throws an error RUN TIME ERROR '1004' - Unable to get the Match property of the Worksheetfunction class.. and highlight the below line of code

```
cel.Interior.ColorIndex = rng.Cells(WorksheetFunction.Match(cel.Value, rng, False), 1).Interior.ColorIndex
```

Also I dont know how to code based on the column name, so it returns the duplicates from all the coulmn from A to Z. Instead I want to highlight only to a selected column.. in which duplicates may also present in AA,AB,AC and more even!

```
Sub DupEntry() 
Dim cel As Variant
Dim rng As Range
Dim clr As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Sample Array of Columns
Dim Col(1 To 26) As String
Col(1) = "A"
Col(2) = "B"
Col(3) = "C"
Col(4) = "D"
Col(5) = "E"
Col(6) = "F"
Col(7) = "G"
Col(8) = "H"
Col(9) = "I"
Col(10) = "J"
Col(11) = "K"
Col(12) = "L"
Col(13) = "M"
Col(14) = "N"
Col(15) = "O"
Col(16) = "P"
Col(17) = "Q"
Col(18) = "R"
Col(19) = "S"
Col(20) = "T"
Col(21) = "U"
Col(22) = "V"
Col(23) = "W"
Col(24) = "X"
Col(25) = "Y"
Col(26) = "Z"
'Iterate through Columns
For i = 1 To 26
Set rng = Range(Col(i) & "1:" & Col(i) & Range(Col(i) & "1048576").End(xlUp).Row)
rng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
clr = 26
For Each cel In rng
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, cel) > 1 Then
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(Col(i) & "1:" & Col(i) & cel.Row), cel) = 1 Then
cel.Interior.ColorIndex = clr
clr = clr + 1
Else
cel.Interior.ColorIndex = rng.Cells(WorksheetFunction.Match(cel.Value, rng, False), 1).Interior.ColorIndex
End If
End If
Next
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: Will the duplicates be on the same row - for example, will the duplicate Employee ID have the same duplicate Register Number.  Or could there be duplicate Register Numbers with different Employee IDs?

Comment: What have you tried? Please show us your code. Also, please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for question guidelines.

Comment: Yes.. There could be same duplicates in other column also @Darren Bartrup-Cook

Answer (score 0):

You can do Conditional Formatting - one of the default options is to check and highlight duplicates.  Highlight the column you want, go to Conditional Formatting, New Rule.  then choose "Format only unique or duplicate values", then choose "Duplicate" in the drop down option in the lower area.  Set the format you want (red background, red text, etc.) and hit "Ok"

Comment: No.. I don't wanna give conditional formatting as the column which we need to find the duplicates always changes..